# Use case or if in Table Value function to run query based on passed in value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to use a table-valued function (TVF) to execute one of 2 queries based on the value passed in. If the value passed in is NULL, I want to return all rows. If the value is specified, I want only those rows where the parameter equals the value specified.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[search_test]
    (@param int)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN
        IF (@param = NULL)
            SELECT TOP 500 recordID 
            FROM jct_RecordParameter 
            ORDER BY recordID

        IF (@param >= 0)
            SELECT TOP 500 recordID 
            FROM jct_RecordParameter 
            WHERE parameterID = @param 
            ORDER BY recordID
END
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near keyword 'if'

When I replace "RETURN" with "BEGIN," the syntax error shifts to "near 'BEGIN'".

Comment: You started your definition as a iTVF (inline Table Value Function) but then attempted to define it as an mlTVF (multi-line TVF). In truth, this logic doesn't belong in a function at all. This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clearly shows how different functions are structured.

Comment: @ThomA, it's not so much that I don't know which problem I'm looking to solve, it's more a case of not knowing there was a different way to solve the problem and that there are 2 different types of tvfs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an `IF` statement in a Table-valued function. But you can use an `OR` condition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[search_test] (@param int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 500 recordID
    FROM jct_RecordParameter
    WHERE (@param IS NULL) OR (parameterID = @param)
    ORDER BY recordID
)
```

Comment: Note that if the parameter is hard-coded then the `OR` is elided to whichever side it is.